# Verify if a curve partially lies on a subvariety

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, differential-geometry

Let $X\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be a surface defined by $\{F=0\}$, with $F$ a polynomial of degree $n>1$ in $x,y,z$.

Choose $p\in X$ and $v\in T_pX$.

Let $\gamma:[-1,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be a $C^\infty$ curve such that $\gamma(0)=p$ and $\gamma'(0)=v$.

I have to find a way to verify if $\gamma$ spends some time on $X$ (i.e. there exists a $\epsilon>0$ such that $\gamma((-\epsilon,\epsilon))\subset X$ without knowing the equations of $\gamma$ but knowing only $\gamma(0),\gamma'(0)$ and $\gamma''(0)$.

This is my attempt: if $\gamma$ spends some time on $X$ then $v+\gamma''(0)t$ will be a tangent vector to $X$ in $p+vt$ for $t\in \mathbb{R}$ small, so I have to verify if $v+\gamma''(0)t$ is in $Ker(dF_{p+vt})$.

I'm trying to do a second order approximation of $\gamma$.

Is my method correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\gamma$ spends sometimes in $X$ is equivalent to saying that there exists $c>0$ such that for every $t\in (-c,c)$, $\gamma(t)\in X$. This is equivalent to say that $F(\gamma(t))=0$ for $t\in (-c,c)$. You can differentiate this equation and obtain $dF(\gamma'(t))_{t\in (-c,c) }=0$ in particular $dF(v)= dF(\gamma'(0)$.

$dF(\gamma'(t))=0, t\in (-c,c)$ implies $d^2F.(\gamma'(t),\gamma'(t))+dF.\gamma"(t)=0$ in particular $d^2F.(\gamma'(0),\gamma'(0))+dF(\gamma"(0))=0$.

Comment: yes of course, this is the obviuos way, but I said I just know $\gamma(0),\gamma'(0)$ and $\gamma''(0)$. What you say is obvious, but I don't know the equation of $\gamma$ and so $\gamma'(t)$ for $t\neq 0$. What I'm trying to do is some sort of second order approximation of $\gamma$.

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean with $d^2F.(\gamma"(0),\gamma'(0))+dF(\gamma"(0))=0$? what is $\cdot$ and $(\gamma"(0),\gamma'(0))$?

Comment: the second derivative is a bilinear form, I just compute the differential of $dF_{\gamma(t)}.(\gamma'(t))$.

Comment: so you're saying that "$\gamma$ spends some time on $X$" is equivalent to $d^2F.(\gamma'(0),\gamma'(0))+dF(\gamma"(0))=0$?

Comment: You have to add $dF.\gamma'(0)=0$ and $F(\gamma(0))=0$ and it is one way.